# what does *appropriately distributed* mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

what does "appropriately distributed" mean in the following sentence? what does it refer to? (emphasis added)

> Where public agencies or community
>   bodies have the administrative capacities, **contractual arrangements
>   that set fees can help deliver quality services**, ***appropriately distributed***.

Hear is the whole paragraph:

> Competition from private schools and health providers is an important
>   spur to competition, and the main source of growth in supply for lower-income
>   groups is access to privately supplied services, with some assistance
>   from vouchers and targeted subsidies. Where public agencies or community
>   bodies have the administrative capacities, contractual arrangements
>   that set fees can help deliver quality services, appropriately distributed.

[*Development Economics through the Decades: A Critical Look at 30 Years of the World Development Report*, Shahid Yusuf, page 38.](https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/bitstream/handle/10986/2586/47108.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Comment: I think you are asking what the phrase _appropriately distributed_ modifies in this sentence. If so, the answer is "quality services." If you replace the comma with "that are", it's easier to understand: "quality services (that are) appropriately distributed."

Comment: @P.E.Dant if so, then "appropriately distributed" is an adjective for quality services, or is a "kind of" quality services or even is always a "characteristic" of quality services. I am really baffled.

Comment: Not always: in the _specific_ case described. The sense is that if the agencies do not have the capacity called for, these contractual arrangements might not deliver "appropriately distributed" services. For clarity, shorten and analyze just the second clause: _contractual arrangements can deliver services (that are) appropriately distributed._ Do you understand now?

Answer (score 1):

"distributed as appropriate" would be an alternate wording you may find better.  Though it is not defining what the writer considers appropriate, it means that it should be distributed to recipients in some manner that would be deemed fair.  For instance, not all of the benefit should be given to a single receiver.